# How to prove a symmetric tensor is indeed a tensor?

Tags: tensors, symmetry, general-relativity

Our professor defined a rank (k,l) tensor as something that transforms like a tensor as follows:

$$T^{\mu_1' \mu_2'...\mu_k'}{}_{\nu_1'\nu_2'...\nu_l'} ~=~ \Lambda^{\mu_1'}{}_{\mu_1}...\Lambda^{\mu_k'}{}_{\mu_k}~\Lambda^{\nu_1}{}_{\nu_1'}...\Lambda^{\nu_l}{}_{\nu_l'}~T^{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_k}{}_{\nu_1\nu_2...\nu_l}$$

Where $\Lambda$ are the Lorentz transformation matrices (translations, rotations, or boosts). I'm not sure if this is only for SR or if also for GR since we've only been talking about SR thus far, though GR is something we'll be covering soon.

He wrote on the whiteboard: if $S_{\mu\nu\rho}=S_{\nu\mu\rho}$ then S is symmetric in $\mu$ and $\nu$.

**But let's just talk about a rank (2,0) symmetric contravariant tensor for a second, denoted $S^{\mu\nu}$ and equals $S^{\nu\mu}$. How would we prove this is a tensor?** Our book uses $R$ in place of $\Lambda$ in their formulations above, where $R$ might just be rotations. I'm sure General Tensors would have any jacobian and inverse jacobians are matrices rather than just the Lorentz transformations.

Also if you want to give a student like myself who is new to tensor some advice on learning tensors, and some tensor properties, and how to work with them, be my guest :)

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/206739/2451

Comment: I wasn't going to crosspost it but after many hours waiting for an answer on math.stackexchange I thought maybe it'd be better to post it on the physics one.